# How to create a button in ActionBar with icon and text?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I want to create a button in ActionBar with text and icon. Something like on the screenshot below.
[image]

I've tried this code. But it doesn't work. It displays only icon without text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/create"
          android:title="@string/create"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_apply"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: What is the status of this?

Answer (score 5):

Read up on [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

Since Toolbar is basically a ViewGroup, you can add child views. An example :

```
<Toolbar
    android:id = "@+id/myToolbar"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:minHeight = "?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background = "?attr/colorPrimary" > 

    <Button
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:text = "My button"
        android:layout_gravity = "right" />
</Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

If you mentioned `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`
it is considered as Action bar button.

Inflating Menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Handling Click event:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `AppCompat`:

Your question maybe similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262141/950427

Make sure you bringing in the correct namespace: `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Here is the example from the docs:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

    ...
</menu>
```

Explanation from the docs:

> Using XML attributes from the support library Notice that the
>   showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the
>    tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by
>   the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the
>   Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace
>   as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

Comment: Please look at my answer. You need to use the correct namespace if you are using `AppCompat` Are you using `AppCompat`?

Comment: No, I don't use AppCompat, only SDK

Answer (score 0):

You can create different xml layout for actionbar and in that use buttons or text.
Example:

actionbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="Enter Text"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

use actionbar.xml in java file:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();

Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action2);  
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
TextView title;

getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actiobar); 
title= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("BUSINESS");
```